# How do I turn off code readonly mode while app is running in Rider IDE?

Tags: rider

I turned it on in popup window and now I'm searching for a place in settings where I can turn it off. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be `Allow editing in debug mode`.

[image: Allow editing in debug mode]